# Get attributes value in Puppeteer using xpath

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer to automate a UI. I need to fetch an attribute value of a certain element, and I am using xpath to locate the element.

xpath:

```
//div[text()="5546800"]//following::div[@col-id="21"] .
```

I am getting an error "Failed to execute 'queryselector' on 'Document:

```
//div[text()="5546800"]//following::div[@col-id="21"] is not a valid selector
```

Below is the code I used:

```
const attributes=await page.$eval('//div[text()="5546800"]//following::div[@col-id="21"]',el =>el.getAttributes('type'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use XPath expressions in `page.$eval`, but you can create elementHandle with [`page.$x`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&show=api-pagexexpression) that can be passed to [`page.evaluate`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args):

```js
const attributes = await page.evaluate(el => el.getAttribute('type'), (await page.$x('//div[text()="5546800"]//following::div[@col-id="21"]'))[0])
```

FYI: I am not sure if you wanted to use `getAttributes()` and not [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) or [`getAttributeNames()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttributeNames).

#### Edit

Sorry, I made two typos in the previous version of this answer:

- fixed closing single quote
- XPath `$x` returns an array of element handles (just like `$$` and not like `$`) so you need to use an index of the desired element. You also need to group the `await`-ed expression with parenthesis!
  `await page.$x('//div[text()="5546800"]//following::div[@col-id="21"]')` => `(await page.$x('//div[text()="5546800"]//following::div[@col-id="21"]'))[0]`

Comment: Getting the below error :  ' Type Error: Converting circular structure to JSON , starting at object with constructor  'Browser '

Comment: @RaishulAlam sorry, my bad. I made one typo and one mistake in the snippet. the element handle was an array, so you need to select its first element by the `[0]` index to avoid circular structure. see my edit above.